Common Method to switch Activities
I am trying to find out whether we can create a common method to switch between activities and while doing so I thought to write code as:
private fun goToActivity(activity: AppCompatActivity){
    val intent = Intent(this, activity::class.java)
    startActivity(intent)
}

calling the method
    goToActivity(MainActivity2())

Is this the a good to do this thing or any other method that saves rewriting the piece of code again and again written in "goToActivity"?

The reason you shouldn’t do it your way is that you are instantiating a useless instance of your Activity that will immediately be thrown away. That’s a lot of overhead and possibly unintended side effects for no benefit. Am Activity should never be instantiated directly.

Try this. Below will handle all your needs.
/**
     * @param context          Context fromactivity or fragment
     * @param bundle           Bundle of values for next Activity
     * @param destinationClass Destination Activity
     * @param isFinish         Current activity need to finish or not
     */
    public void newIntent(Context context, Class destinationClass, Bundle bundle, boolean isFinish, boolean isFlags) {
        if (!isActivityRunning(context)) {
            return;
        }
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, destinationClass);
        intent.putExtras(bundle);
        if (isFlags) {
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        }
        context.startActivity(intent);
        if (isFinish) {
            ((Activity) context).finish();
        }
    }

CommonFunctions.getInstance().newIntent(OrdersActivity.this, HomeActivity.class, Bundle.EMPTY, true,true);
Use bundle like this
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putString("name", "");
CommonFunctions.getInstance().newIntent(this, CartViewActivity.class, bundle, false, false);

